# default directory permissions redhat linux

Tags: permissions, rhel

How can I set default group owner & permissions for any new file created under /data/user-name/ ?

I want any new file created under /data/user-name/ to have the following properties: 1) group owner = marketing 2) owner permissions = rwx 3) group permissions = rwx 4) other permissions = r--

```
touch /data/user-name/test.file
ls -lah /data/user-name/test.file
```

should produce

```
-rwxrwxr--  1 username marketing     0B Apr  7 13:23 test.file
```

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The default permissions for a new file are 0666, i.e. rw-rw-rw-.  These permissions can be reduced, i.e masked off, using `umask`.  There is no default mechanism to add execute permissions when creating a file.

Comment: Wow, ok. Thank you! That may be ok for my use-case. There might be some masking settings on my server, then. Do you know how to apply default group owner to new files under a directory?